# Swapping limit and infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I have an expression of the form

$$ \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \lim_{\delta \to 0} \sum_{j,k=1}^\infty f(j,k,\epsilon, \delta)$$

such that the infinite double sum is absolutely convergent, even for $\epsilon = \delta = 0$, and that $f$ is continuous with respect to both $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ for every $j,k$. Can I then swap the limits with the sum?

Of course, we might also write it as
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \lim_{\delta \to 0} \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} g(m,n,\epsilon, \delta),$$

where $g(m,n,\epsilon, \delta) := \sum_{j=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n f(j,k,\epsilon, \delta)$, so that the question becomes whether we can bring the outer limits inside.

I think that this should be possible since we have very generous assumptions, but I am not sure about what theorem exactly implies that it is feasible, and whether the key fact is continuity of $f$ or absolute convergence of the sum or both.

Answer (score 1):

One general approch is to interpret summation as integration over $(\mu,\mathbb{N^2}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N^2}))$, where $\mu$ is the counting measure. So the equation in question can be written as
$$\int_{\mathbb{N}^2} f(j,k,\varepsilon,\delta) \, \mathrm{d}\mu(j,k).$$
Thus, we now may apply the dominated convergence thoerem.

Your assumpations are insufficient for swapping the limits! For example define $f_\varepsilon(n) = \varepsilon n^{-1-\varepsilon}.$ This function is continuous for fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Moreover, we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_0(n) =0$, but $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_\epsilon(n) \gg \int_1^\infty f_\varepsilon(x) \, \mathrm{d}x =1.$$

Comment: Thanks! I don't understand your last line, though. Where is the $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}$ that we want to swap? Aren't the sum and the integral really one and the same thing? And why is the integral equal to $1$?

Comment: In fact, we cannot let $\epsilon \downarrow 0$, because we don't checked the convergence. However, if the limis exists, it must be $\gg 1$. This shows that we cannot swap the limits, because $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_0(n) =0$. In order to deduce the last inequality, use the integral test for convergence (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence)) The integral can be directly computed: $\int_1^\infty\varepsilon x^{-1-\varepsilon} \mathrm{dx} = \left. - x^{-\varepsilon} \right|_{x=1}^\infty =1$

Comment: Yes, the sum and the integrad are the same thing! Note that integrable corresponds to absolute convergence. (Thus, not absolute convergent series cannot be interpreted as a Lebesgue-integral over the couting measure.)